# How to display a TextView below an other one in Android with XML files?

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

I am pretty sure that a parameter will do the trick but I can't find the one I am looking for.

I am trying to display one TextView -file_type- below the file_title TextView.

What would be the parameter that I should add to the file_type TevxtView block to come under the file_title TextView block ?

There is what I am doing :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ImageView android:id="@+id/file_type_logo"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:paddingLeft="25px"
      android:paddingTop="25px" />

  <TextView android:id="@+id/file_title"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:paddingLeft="30px"
     android:textSize="22sp"
     android:background="#FF0000"
     android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

  <TextView android:id="@+id/file_type"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:paddingLeft="30px"
     android:paddingTop="10px"
     android:layout_gravity="bottom"
     android:textSize="22sp"
     android:background="#FF0000"
     android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you ,

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By default linearlayout wraps things horizontally. If you want the imageview to be at the left of the both textviews (that are wrapped vertically), use following:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ImageView .../>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView1..../>

    <TextView2..../>

 </LinearLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Or you can just pass the parameter `android:orientation="vertical"` to the top level LinearLayout. Have a look at RelativeLayout definition as well.

Comment: Definitely do the latter suggestion (orientation="vertical") to avoid too many nested layouts, but yeah, either one will work for you.

Comment: You saved me :) Thanks!